# Python 3.5 pip installation of numpy error

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pip

So I am trying to install numpy for python 3.5. I have downloaded numpy and unzipped it to the Python35 file. Using the cmd prompt I have run:

> C:\Users\[my name]>C:\Python35|Scripts\pip install numpy

This resulted in the error:

> Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'

I have tried

> setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python34\Scripts"

and running the 'pip install numpy'. And all of the above with the 'NumPy' variation and pip3 and pip3.5

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Installing numpy using `pip` requires compiling a load of C extensions, so `pip install numpy` will fail unless you have a working toolchain set up. It would be much easier to install numpy using one of the prepackaged scientific Python distributions, e.g. [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), or from a pre-built Windows binary, [such as those hosted by Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Comment: I also have similar problems when trying to install it, and as @ali_m said, is more easy to install numpy by installing Anaconda, and you also get other cool stuff with it

Comment: thanks for your help, i was unaware of this bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Download numpy from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)!
then go to command prompt and install it it

Example:

```
pip install "put path here"
```